# Unable to access Actuator when a springboot application is running via a fat jar file on an application server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am a little out of my league on this one as I am still getting familiar with everything Springboot.  Onto my problem...

I am unable to access actuator for an application that is running in a fat jar file on an application server.  All works great when I run the application locally through Eclipse as I am perfectly able to access a couple of the endpoints (health, logfile) via a browser and Postman.

However, when I attempt to access those same endpoints (via curl, a browser or Postman) using the application server's url, I get a 404. I am able to access other custom written apis within the application with no issue, just not actuator apis.

I know I am missing something very obvious, but cannot figure out what that is.

Good - http://localhost:9091/actuator/health  --> from a browser or Postman

Not good - http://my-app-testserver-01:9090/actuator/health or `curl localhost:9090/actuator/health`and both yield the below error.  NOTE that the curl is performed on the application server.

`"timestamp":"2022-06-30T20:57:12.191+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/actuator/health"`

What else?  Oh yeah, below is a snippet from my yml file pertaining to actuator and I believe that is ok.

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

````
management:
  server:
    port: 9090
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info,logfile" ```
````

Comment: Can you do a `netstat -lan` on the application server to check if anything is listening on 9090/9091 and see what interface address it's listening on?

Comment: @Hopey One - Thanks for the quick response.  It looks like the net-tools package is not installed on the server and I'll need to get someone to install it (tried but do not have permissions) and then I'll do as you suggested.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Hopey One - I am all set now.  The ports had to be opened for me on the new server.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all set now.  I was setting up the application on a new server and had to have the ports opened up for me.  Once that was done I was able to access the Actuator apis with no issues.